# Perl: alter a string by regex match

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using this code to alter a string by a regex match.

```
$a->{'someone'} = "a _{person}";
$a->{'person'} = "gremlin";

$string = "_{someone} and a thing"
while($string =~ /(_\{(.*?)\}/g){
    $search = metaquote($1);
    $replace = $a->{$2};
    $string =~ s/$search/$replace/;
}
```

The result is `a _{person} and a thing` but I'm expecting: `a gremlin and a thing`.

What to do to get this working?

Comment: Always `use strict;` so you will avoid many problems

Comment: I don't know what code you're running to get that result. What you have published hash three syntax errors and so won't compile. When they are fixed it does exactly what you say you want.

Comment: Thanks to choroba he fixed the compile errors. I'm sorry just typed what I remembered from my troubles today. I'm now wondering why it haven't worked earlier this day. I must have a look into the real problem again tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is called `quotemeta`, not `metaquote`. Also, a right parenthesis is missing in your regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $a;

$a->{'someone'} = "a _{person}";
$a->{'person'}  = "gremlin";

my $string = "_{someone} and a thing";
while($string =~ /(_\{(.*?)\})/g){
    my $search  = quotemeta($1);
    my $replace = $a->{$2};
    $string =~ s/$search/$replace/;
}
print "$string\n";
```

I also added `strict` and `warnings` to help myself avoid common pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be more effecient variant:

```
use strict;
my $a;
$a->{'someone'} = "a _{person}";
$a->{'person'} = "gremlin";

my $string = "_{someone} and a thing";
while( $string =~ s/(_\{(.*?)\})/ $a->{$2} /ges ) {}
print $string."\n";
```

Comment: This is a poor piece of code, not least because it will loop indefinitely if the relevant hash element doesn't exist. You really should test your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This variant repeatedly substitues *all* of the placeholders in the string for their corresponding hash value until there are none left.

In addition, `a` is a bad identifier for any variable, so I have named it `tokens`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %tokens = (
  someone => 'a _{person}',
  person  => 'gremlin',
);

my $string = '_{someone} and a thing';

1 while $string =~ s/_\{([^}]+)\}/$tokens{$1}/g;

print $string, "\n";
```

**output**

```
a gremlin and a thing
```

Comment: @hobbs: It substitutes a null string just like the original. It also raises a warning because it has uninitialized warnings enabled, which I think is desirable.